# How to clear the buffer of Ionic.Zip dot.net library due Is trying to .zip the previous file zipped in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ionic-framework, zip

i'm having a problem while trying to zip a file with dot.net zip library, If I zip my first file it do it well, but when I'm trying to zip a 2nd file, is throwing an exception and the message that appear is that the file was not found (the 1st. one that I zip) due I deleted that file.
the problem is that is trying to zip the previous file as well, there's a way to clean the buffer or something like that? this is my portion of code.

```
 private void zipFile(string FileToZip) 
        {
            try
            {                    
                if (DataFile.sZipPassword.Length > 0)
                {
                    zip.Password = DataFile.sZipPassword;
                }               
                zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
                zip.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Deflate;             
                zip.AddFile(FileToZip, "");              
                zip.Save(FileToZip + ".zip");
                //zip.Dispose();                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sResult = "Unable to zip the file " + FileToZip + message.NewLine + "Error: " + ex.Message;
                NotificationEmail(sResult, DataFile.sEmailDistributionFailure, message.EmailFailedLegend);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is zip a member variable? How do you initialize it?

Comment: I did it at the top of of my code:
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

Comment: So all you have to do is reinitialize it

Comment: Thank you very much! it work perfectly!